# An react error is throwing showing that "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endOf')" whenever I am compiling my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, openweathermap

Here is the code but I have imported everything perfectly, it is still showing the error. At first  i thought it had to do something with my npm and node version. But i checked and saw that it was perfectly fine and it was working perfectly a while ago. Suddenly only after compiling once this error started popping off.

```
import React from "react";
import cities from "../../lib/city.list.json";
import TodaysWeather from "../../components/TodaysWeather";
import HourlyWeather from "../../components/HourlyWeather";
import WeeklyWeather from "../../components/WeeklyWeather";
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import SearchBox from "../../components/SearchBox";
import moment from "moment-timezone";

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const city = getCityId(context.params.city);

  if (!city) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${city.coord.lat}&lon=${city.coord.lon}&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}&exclude=minutely&units=metric`
  );

  const data = await res.json();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  const hourlyWeather = getHourlyWeather(data.hourly, data.timezone);

  const weeklyWeather = data.daily;

  return {
    props: {
      city: city,
      timezone: data.timezone,
      currentWeather: data.current,
      hourlyWeather: hourlyWeather,
      weeklyWeather: weeklyWeather,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

const getCityId = (param) => {
  const cityParam = param.trim();
  // get the id of the city
  const splitCity = cityParam.split("-");
  const id = splitCity[splitCity.length - 1];

  if (!id) {
    return null;
  }

  const city = cities.find((city) => city.id.toString() == id);

  if (city) {
    return city;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

const getHourlyWeather = (hourlyData, timezone) => {
  const endOfDay = moment().tz(timezone).endOf("day").valueOf();
  const eodTimeStamp = Math.floor(endOfDay / 1000);

  const todaysData = hourlyData.filter((data) => data.dt < eodTimeStamp);

  return todaysData;
};

export default function City({
  city,
  weather,
  currentWeather,
  hourlyWeather,
  weeklyWeather,
  timezone,
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{city.name} Weather - Next Weather App</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="page-wrapper">
        <div className="container">
          <Link href="/">
            <a className="back-link">&larr; Home</a>
          </Link>
          <SearchBox placeholder="Search for another location..." />
          <TodaysWeather
            city={city}
            weather={weeklyWeather[0]}
            timezone={timezone}
          />
          <HourlyWeather hourlyWeather={hourlyWeather} timezone={timezone} />
          <WeeklyWeather weeklyWeather={weeklyWeather} timezone={timezone} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endOf')
    at getHourlyWeather (D:\next-weather-app-main\next-weather-app-main\.next\server\pages\location\[city].js:3958:89)
s\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:39:215)
    at async D:\next-weather-app-main\next-weather-app-main\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:112:97
    at async D:\next-weather-app-main\next-weather-app-main\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:105:142
    at async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents (D:\next-weather-app-main\next-weather-app-main\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:137:387)
    at async DevServer.renderToHTML (D:\next-weather-app-main\next-weather-app-main\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:138:1088)
    at async DevServer.renderToHTML (D:\next-weather-app-main\next-weather-app-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-server.js:36:578)
```

[image: Error after being compiled]

Comment: `timezone` in ` moment().tz(timezone).endOf("day").valueOf();` is either invalid or `undefined`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn invalid _timezone_ still returns a moment instance (while also logging an error). Only an `undefined` arg results in `undefined`

Comment: I suggest you look closely at the result you get from OpenWeatherMap. For whatever reason, it seems `data.timezone` is undefined